# Jsdom throws an error on a external resource script (script on the page) after returning the result

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, jsdom, cheerio

I am getting an error which seems to be originating from one of the page scripts.

```
file://cdn.widgets.webengage.com/js/widget/webengage-min-v-3.0.js:1
return c.apply(undefined,a)}catch(d){webengage.eLog(d);if(!b){throw d}}}else{t
                                                                    ^
TypeError: Cannot call method 'call' of undefined
    at new exports.NOT_IMPLEMENTED (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/browser/utils.js:9:13)
    at Object.webengage.eLog (file://cdn.widgets.webengage.com/js/widget/webengage-min-v-3.0.js:1:366)
    at t.extend.u (file://cdn.widgets.webengage.com/js/widget/webengage-min-v-3.0.js:1:19160)
    at Object.t.extend.error (file://cdn.widgets.webengage.com/js/widget/webengage-min-v-3.0.js:1:19299)
    at file://cdn.widgets.webengage.com/js/widget/webengage-min-v-3.0.js:1:66518
    at Object.webengage.withELog (file://cdn.widgets.webengage.com/js/widget/webengage-min-v-3.0.js:1:640)
    at Timer.<anonymous> (file://cdn.widgets.webengage.com/js/widget/webengage-min-v-3.0.js:1:937)
    at Timer.exports.setInterval.timer.ontimeout (timers.js:234:14)
```

I am getting this error from the following code:

```
try {
  var document = jsdom.jsdom(str, null, {});  
} catch(e) {
  console.log("Got ERROR...");
  console.log(e);
}
console.log("Page Document Loaded.");
var window = document.parentWindow;
//console.log(window.document.innerHTML);
console.log(window.innerWidth);
console.log(typeof window.document.getElementsByClassName);
```

here `str` is the html that i got earlier. I am able to see printed results, the html the innerWidth and the typeof getElementsByClassName i.e.. function. But after around 20 seconds i am getting the above error and my application crashes, without printing `Got ERROR...` from above.

The first question that i have is why is my application still running after printing the last thing. Is this a normal behavior for jsdom that it keeps on running like how in a browser a script keeps on running until window.close() is given.

The actual problem is, how can i resolve this. I want to trigger few events in this window object and interact with it but it keeps on crashing.

The url for the script is a little confusing:
`file://cdn.widgets.webengage.com/js/widget/webengage-min-v-3.0.js:1`

this is because the page is fetching this script resource in an ajax call with the url:
`//cdn.widgets.webengage.com/js/widget/webengage-min-v-3.0.js:1`

although jsdom is able to get the resource, i checked that this script has that line where it is showing the error.

Comment: i found a place where someone is talking about a similar problem, but as a side note: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14003549/907753

Comment: i have seen the cause of the problem and it turns out that the script in question is executing a=new Image() where it is causing the problem. which i suppose is not yet implemented in jsdom. and thus throwing this error. is their a way to suppress these errors altogether.

Comment: This particular problem seems to haven gotten resolved by defining an `Image` property on `window` like this: `window.Image = function () { };` i got help from domenic over here https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom/issues/682

Comment: I am just curious if their is some way to suppress these kinds of errors caused by `NOT_IMPLEMENTED`. It seems to be getting suppressed for other kinds of `NOT_IMPLEMENTED` functionality, but why not this?

Comment: I'm getting the same but with a broken timeout. I just caught and ignored that error, but it doesn't feel like the most robust solution :-)

Comment: yes, as you never know what other kinds of similar exceptions occur in the future, unless you ignore all kinds of errors which is also not the right move. Anyway i ended up using `cheerio` for all the light data collection needs where the requirement is to get a correct DOM structure, for even a malformed html, along with jQuery. for all rest i decided to go with `phantomjs`